# Simulating human mouse movement

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

Hi I'm currently trying to create a program that moves the cursor from a given point to another in one smooth randomised motion. I currently have created the following using CoreGraphics, which works but the mouse movement gets very choppy. Any ideas on how to fix this? Much appreciated. I call the following at the start of my Mac OS X Application inside applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
var pos = NSEvent.mouseLocation()
pos.y = NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.height - pos.y
moveMouse(CGPoint(x:200,y:200), from: pos)
```

And these are the functions I've created:

```
func transMouse(point:CGPoint) {
    let move = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(nil, CGEventType.MouseMoved, point, CGMouseButton.Left)
    CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation.CGHIDEventTap, move)
}

func moveMouseOne(direction:Character, _ currentPos:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    var newPos = currentPos

    if direction == "r" {
        newPos.x = currentPos.x + 1
    } else if direction == "l" {
        newPos.x = currentPos.x - 1
    } else if direction == "u" {
        newPos.y = currentPos.y - 1
    } else if direction == "d" {
        newPos.y = currentPos.y + 1
    }
    transMouse(newPos)

    return newPos
}

func moveMouse(to:CGPoint, from:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    let dx:Int = Int(to.x - from.x)
    let dy:Int = Int(to.y - from.y)

    var moves = Array<Character>()

    if dx > 0 {
        for _ in 0..<dx {
            moves.append("r")
        }
    } else {
        for _ in 0..<(-dx) {
            moves.append("l")
        }
    }

    if dy > 0 {
        for _ in 0..<dy {
            moves.append("d")
        }
    } else {
        for _ in 0..<(-dy) {
            moves.append("u")
        }
    }
    var pos = from
    let delay:Double = 0.0008
    let startTime = DISPATCH_TIME_NOW
    for var i = 0; i < moves.count; ++i {
        let time = dispatch_time(startTime, Int64(delay * Double(i) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let count = moves.count
            let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            pos = self.moveMouseOne(moves[random], pos)
            if random == count - 1 {
                moves.popLast()
            } else {
                moves[random] = moves.popLast()!
            }
        }
    }

    return to
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I really recommend using Core Animation for something like this, will save you a lot of time and effort.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I don't see how I can manipulate the mouse using CoreAnimation, could you explain some more?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood - do you want to move the actual mouse cursor programmatically? Or are you wanting to move something else?

Comment: Yes I want to move the actual mouse cursor. But as far as I can see that's not something core animation can do right?

Comment: Yep - apologies - I think core Animation can only animate views